# Spring Boot and transaction boundary

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, lazy-loading, spring-transactions

I'm using Spring boot for rest back end system with spring data , 
I have three main layers (controller,service , dao).

I annotated the service class with @Transactional and within one of it's methods i'm retrieving some entity having @ManyToMany relationship with other Entity .

I want only to get the main entity and i'm depending on the lazy of the @ManyToMany.

The problem is after returning back from the service to the controller when I hit on the (many) side a sql statement is issues and retrieved the collection as if the transaction is still running !!

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = { "net.pd.ethraa" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "net.pd.ethraa.dao" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = "net.pd.ethraa.common.model")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class EthraaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}

 @RequestMapping(path = "/get/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Account getAccount(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Account account = accountService.find(id);

    for (Permission p : account.getPermissions()) {
        System.out.println(p.getName());
    }
    return account;

    }


@Service
@Transactional
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

 @Override
    public Account find(Long id) {
    return accountDao.findOne(id);

    }
}

@Repository
public interface AccountDao extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {}


@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "mobile", "email" }))
public class Account extends BaseEntity {
 @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ACCOUNT_PERMISSION")
    private List<Permission> permissions;
}
```

My expectation is when I hit the collection outside the service it should be outside the transaction boundary and gives lazy exception but it doesn't ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot enables [`OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html) by default which allows for this behavior.

You can disable it using following property in your application config file:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

Comment: Is it true for all the scenarios ? Does Spring boot turns this on through some application property/ annotation/ class ? Please guide . I tried an example in latest versions of spring boot >1.4.2. I got lazy load exception.

Comment: This option should default to `true` in the current Spring Boot version. Complete conditions for registration of this interceptor can be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration.java#L185). If you are having issues try starting a separate question with your example please.